# How do I use Excel VBA to loop through a list of websites?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have built an Excel Macro that pulls data from a table on my website but there are many other parts of the site I would like to pull from. I have placed the list of URLs in Column A and would like the Macro to keep going down the list and pulling from the same exact table, essentially pulling data from the web like my existing Macro but using the link in the next cell down after each loop.
The end result hopefully being one long sheet that has the data from all the pages linked to in Column A. Can anyone with knowledge of VBA help out?

This is the Macro so far. It simply pulls from a specific table in my site. But I don't know how to add the looping function that would go down the list of URLs.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://mywebsite.com/", Destination:= _
        Range("$B$1"))
        .Name = "clients"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "8"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: Show your existing code.  Which exact part of your question are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign the range to a collection listOfURLs = Range("A2:A15") 
   or
2. Iterate through the rows cells(row,1) and row=row+1 inside a loop

It's better to use the array or collection as it would perform faster